# removing id attribute from an existing element

Tags: jquery

i am trying to remove the id attribute that is associated with eng_app whats wrong with the below code i see the id attribute still.I see the log inside if

This is the code i tried so  far

```
 var htm = $("#addin").find(".eng_data:first-child").html();
 if($(htm).find(".eng_app"))
 {
    console.log("Inside if");
console.log($(this).removeAttr("id"));
 }
 var new_htm = "<div class='eng_data'>" +htm+"</div>";                                  
 $("#addin").append(new_htm);
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="eng_data" class="eng_data">


      <select class="eng_app">
      <option value="-1" selected="">Choose application</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" class="grades"  placeholder="grades"/>
      <a href="#" ><img src="images/add.gif" width="21" class="addrow"/></a>

      </div>
```

Comment: can you post your markup

Comment: Have you tried `$("#addin .eng_data:first-child").find(".eng_app").removeAttr("id")` ?

Comment: add fiddle...........

Comment: i have tried this , $("#addin .eng_data:first-child").find(".eng_app").removeAttr("id")

Comment: @Hulk, nice that you posted the html. Were is #addin ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$("#addin").find(".eng_data:first-child").children(".eng_app").removeAttr('id');
```

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$(htm).find(".eng_app").removeAttr('id');
```

hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

You should do this:

```
$(htm).find(".eng_app").removeAttr('id');
console.log($(htm).find(".eng_app").attr('id'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
var htm = $("#addin").find(".eng_data:first-child").html();
var eng_app = $(htm).find(".eng_app");
if (eng_app.length > 0)
{
    eng_app.removeAttr("id");
    console.log(eng_app.attr("id"));
}
var new_htm = "<div class='eng_data'>" + htm + "</div>";                                  
$("#addin").append(new_htm);
```

Your problems were:

1. `if($(htm).find(".eng_app"))` would always return true, as even if there were no matches it would create an empty array. My suggestion tests the `length` instead.
2. I don't think you were in a context where `this` had been mapped, so it would still have just referred to the `window` object.

Hope this helps.